# Scrape StreetEasy Page with Login Requirement

Tags: python, html, scrape

I am currently working on real-estate data and wanted to scrape some data from StreetEasy, which is the `Register to see what it closed for about 2 months ago` below listed price.

Example url
[http://streeteasy.com/sale/1220187](http://Register%20to%20see%20what%20it%20closed%20for%20about%202%20months%20ago)

The data I need requires login but the login mechanism is pretty different. There is no login page and the login is a pop-up. Is there anyway I can use Python to get the authentication and accesss the page after login like the image below?

Comment: I'm actually doing something very similar, mind you, not with real estate websites.  Have you thought about using something like "phantomjs" and "selenium"?

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium and PhantomJS, you get a powerful combination when it comes to scraping data.

```
from selenium import webdriver

host = "http://streeteasy.com/sale/1220187"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# Set the "window" wide enough so PhantomJS can "see" the right panel
driver.set_window_size(1280, 800)
driver.get(host)

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Register to see what it closed for").click()

driver.save_screenshot("output.jpg")
```

What you see is a small snippet of how Selenium can get you to the webpage login (verified via the JPG screencap).  From there, it's a matter of toggling the login box, providing the credentials and `click()`ing your way in.

Oh, and be mindful of the TOS.  Good luck!